# ng-bind and ng-model doesn't work together with same variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my html

```
<uib-accordion-group class="panel-product" data-ng-repeat="row in vm.transaction.data">
                <span uib-accordion-heading>
                    <span>{{row.quantity}}</span> x <span data-ng-bind="row.name"></span><span class="pull-right" data-ng-bind="row.total() | currency"></span>
                </span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label field-label">Price: </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-model="row.salePrice" data-ng-required="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label field-label">Quantity: </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-model="row.quantity" data-ng-required="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label field-label">Discount <small>%</small>: </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" data-ng-minlength="3" data-ng-model="row.discounts[0].value" data-ng-required="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
```

You see row.quantity variable is being used in a ng-model as well as ng-bind, it works fine with ng-model and I can see the value in the input field but the value of quantity is not showing up in the ng-bind span as well as the row.total() function is also not working.

Comment: Well, you're trying to call a method inside your object... Do you have a property called *total*? If so just do this: `data-ng-bind="row.total | currency"` without `()`.

Comment: Create demo that reproduces this. Also we don't know what `row.total()` does without showing the code for it. Does that object have such a method?

Comment: my guess is you are trying to do `vm.total(row)`

Comment: I think quantity value digit have less than 3 value, where it isn't satiesfying `minlength` thats why `quantity` ngmodel isn't getting updated

Comment: the total() function exists and it only do some calculations, the main problem is with the ng-bind not showing quantity. if I remove the ng-bind="row.quantity" from the input i can see the quantity value in the span where it is bound with the tag.

Comment: Show us your *JS* code then.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you guys, I found the problem. data-ng-minlength was causing the problem.  The minlength is set to 3 where the quantity was 1 and since it was an invalid value it wasn't working. I fixed the constraint on the input value and it worked.

Comment: Then delete this question as it has no long term value to anyone else